# three.js cylinder wireframe without diagonals?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, wireframe, diagonal

I am trying to draw a THREE.js wireframe cylinder without the diagonals in the faces.  I am moving the vertices of the cylinder each frame as well, and am wondering if there is a solution to drawing it with quad faces without having to manually create a new set of THREE.Line every frame.  EdgesHelper is flickering because it has to create a new one each frame.

Comment: Have you tried using `EdgesHelper` and modifying the vertices of the helper directly?

Comment: What property does EdgesHelper have to change?  matrixAutoUpdate and matrixWorld are the only properties that I see. How can you access something like 'EdgesHelper.vertices[i].x' ? It would say vertices is undefined

Comment: Ah right... It's using BufferGeometry. Is not that easy, but you can mess with `EdgesHelper.attributes.position.array` by now...

Comment: I'm getting undefined for those properties as well.  The only way it sort of works is by creating a new EdgesHelper every time, but there is a flickering only in the horizontal edges of the cylinder.  Could the flickering be caused by something other than performance?